# Failed to load preset: "@storybook/addon-info" on level 1

Tags: storybook

everything was fine yesterday.
this problem occurs after I installing prop-types in my create-react-app project.
the error message is as follows:
Can someone tell me where the problem is and how to solve it? thank you.
thank you very much .

```
    MacBook-Pro:storybook_test beike$ npm run storybook

> storybook_test@0.1.0 storybook /Users/storybook_test
> start-storybook -p 9009 -s public

info @storybook/react v5.3.18
info 
info => Loading static files from: /Users/storybook_test/public .
info => Loading presets
WARN   Failed to load preset: "@storybook/addon-info" on level 1
ERR! /Users/storybook_test/node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/PropTable/style.css:1
ERR! .info-table {
ERR! ^
ERR! 
ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
ERR!     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/storybook_test/node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/PropTable/components/Table.js:12:1)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/storybook_test/node_modules/@storybook/addon-info/dist/components/PropTable/index.js:37:37)
ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that [@storybook/addon-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-info) is being [superceded](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7246#issuecomment-524883656) by [@storybook/addon-docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-docs). If it's possible for you, I would recommend you to try and replace the library. You can read more about it in this [article](https://medium.com/storybookjs/storybook-docspage-e185bc3622bf).

If you want or need to stick to your original setup, try and add the `@storybook/addon-info` module in the `exlude` option for the `css` loader or tweak the `include` option as mentioned in the comments [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7246).

I didn't test it, but it would go something like:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules = config.module.rules.filter(f => f.test.toString() !== '/\\.css$/')

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules(?!\/@storybook\/addon-info)/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  })

  return config
}
```

I had the same problem, but since I was starting out the project I just switched libraries.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone lands with a similar error:

I removed `@storybook/addon-links` from package.json but forgot to remove it from the `addons` list in `main.ts`.

That resulted in something similar:

```
info => Loading presets
WARN   Failed to load preset: {"type":"presets"} on level 1
ERR! TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
ERR!     at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
ERR!     at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact error as I was integrating Storybook for Next.js and used this code in `.storybook/main.js` :

```
framework: {
  name: "@storybook/nextjs",
  options: {},
}
```

but i forget to add `@storybook/nextjs` to my `devDependencies`.

## fix

ran this to fix the problem:

```
yarn add -D @storybook/nextjs
```

## or

better fix would be to upgrade storybook to be compatible with next.js with the below commands, and with this you won't need the previous command:

If you already have storybook:

```
npx storybook@next init
```

If you haven't added storybook:

```
npx storybook@next upgrade --prerelease
```